# Getting Google Spreadsheet in the Background

Tags: asp.net, google-sheets

We have a Google Spreadsheet from which we wish to load data into our webpage.

I started by using the [Google Spreadsheet APi via C# and the Google API .NET libraries](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_a_list-based_feed) to read the spreadsheet and load it into an html unsorted list.

The spreadhsheet has about 200 rows, but could have more, as it will be updated frequently.  So the problem is that the users have to wait until the spreadsheed data is retrieved and parsed before they can see anything in the webpage (the page is white whilst loading).

How can I load this data in the background whilst the page loads?
I've already written my code in C# and don't much want to spend the time swapping to javascript, but I will if I have to.

Could I use the [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_dynamic_load.ashx) to do this?  I know it will load html, but can I use it to fetch google data?

What can I do here that would be fast and easy?

**[Edit]**

The account that hosts the google spreadsheet is inside a google domain, so it's documents can't be shared to the public as a whole - only to individuals.  The C# libraries allow me to use the account's username and password to log into the account to get the spreadsheet data, and so the spreadsheet doesn't need to be shared at all.  Even if I went with a javascript/ajax solution, I would yet need this functionality.

Comment: I guess noone else has a clue.  There have been 22 views so far from folks with no opinion, no votes, no comments...  I suppose noone uses the google .net libraries for spreadsheets.

Comment: Ha ha - after 112 views and 6 months, nobody has a comment or a vote and I've even had to answer my own question!  Wonderful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this probably isn't the BEST answer, but it IS a solution.  I'd like to see if y'all have a better one.

[Anyway, I found this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Delay-Load-Lazy-Load-UpdatePanel-using-Timer-Control-in-ASP.Net.aspx), which is an example of how to use an `asp:Timer` to delay the calling of a function for a certain amount of time - in my case, long enough for the page itself to load.  At least this way, the user gets to see the page, and can watch the nice loading-gif until the actual content arrives.

It is an AJAXy approach that allows me to keep my c# programming without having to add any javascript.